# How to use multiple forms in Django 2.1?

Tags: python, html, django

Sorry for asking similar questions, but other similar questions/answers do not help me with `Django 2`.

***Question:***
I have two actions, one is to show some data as a table. 
In the second form, I edit this data and will save it as a table using `Django` in the database. Here is some code:

**simple_upload.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile" value="formOne">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**second form:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="mytable" value="formTwo">
    <table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
    <thead>
      <tr>
...

    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    if request.is_ajax():
        return render(request,
                    'project/simple_upload.html',
                    {'section': 'project', 'lines': zipped})
    return render(request,
                'project/list.html',
                {'section': 'project', 'lines': zipped})
return render(request, 'project/simple_upload.html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('', views.simple_upload, name='list'),
...
]
```

**list.html:**

```
...
{% include "project/simple_upload.html" %}
...
```

In this case, only the first `form` works, the second one fails.

**Question 1:** Can I do `if request.method == 'POST'` and `formOne` in request.POST:", I try but it does not react at all.

**Question2:** How can I write two methods and assign them using urls.py?

Comment: Nothing about forms or views has changed in Django 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the data in a table, you can try **Tables2** in Django, this might make things easier for you

Also in your case, you might need to make different views for different forms, Since both of them make a POST request, it will be difficult to differentiate.

You can easily do that by specifying action attribute in form tag.

Form 1

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="view/for/form/1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="myfile" value="formOne">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Form 2

```
<form method="post" action = "view/for/form/2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="mytable" value="formTwo">
<table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
<thead>
  <tr>
...

</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Later you can redirect using json responses to avoid refreshing the page

in your urls.py add

```
url('view/for/form/2', save_form, name='save'),
```

in your views.py

```
def save_form(request):
    #your save logic using request.post
    return redirect('your/current/url')
```

Comment: when you specify action in form you will be redirected to that specific url, you can write a view function for that url

If you can tell me what exactly you are trying to do, I might be able to help you.
Since I am new at this as well, I am not able to understand what are you trying to do.

Tell me the need of form 1 and form 2

Comment: I am sorry but, You said that you need to show some data but in code you are taking a file as input so I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes, I upload a file and then return a list and then using a for loop, I show it in a table in simple_upload.html. The point is that I use <input> instead of <td>, so the user can edit them. At the end I want to store this table to database (models). I can put the whole code here if you like. But I think the logic is clear.

Comment: I am willing to help you so I don't mind looking at your complete code

Comment: Moreover, when you are saving the data you should write some other function to save the data in the database

like for the second form you an write a view named save_data and it gets called whenever you are saving the data, it can use a simple query, and on successful save you can redirect user to the same or different page with a message saying "Save was successful!" or something like that

Comment: I write another function, but I would like to know how to call it? There is conflict in my case. Do you know how to assign them in the urls.py?

Comment: I have added to my previous answer, you can check some of it there
if I am still not helping, I might need to see your code
you can show it to me at other places as well Git or Whtasapp or facebook or anywhere

Comment: with this action="link", link does not exist, Page not found (404)
How can it work?

Comment: you need to pass the link for your view, 
check in the example I gave, 
link in my action is same as the one in my url which redirects to the view named as "save_form"

Comment: It tried that, it does not work. The files are inside images subfolder. You need to install some libraries though. I add the code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obOKTjZ2bV6JbB57oa3xglR9_5N1cTu6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: okay you will have to give me an hour, I am in my office right now and I am not exactly allowed to use stack here :p

Comment: okay, and the file that I upload is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0RqSQ1OGv5thJOWlUhgex1w-1qzJzIl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I checked a little, you have written save/  as action in the url
but in your main urls.py, you dont have anything to handle that url
you need to add a url for 'save/' there

Comment: That does not work either I tried that))) TemplateDoesNotExist at /images/save/

Comment: It is showing that error because there is no html template in the response
Can you try, 
    return HttpResponse("Some string")
in the view function

Comment: I think I fixed it, Its working on my machine
Press the submit button and see if you wanted what I did

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19G6Am1pm-Lo4KzVkGnDRZN0cert_Mfft

Comment: By the way, I got to learn a lot from your project
Sorry that it took toooooo loong to fix it !

Thank you :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try to save it to the model database.